# Vue.js Как сделать проверку на кол-во символов?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь сделать проверку на то, через что авторизован пользователь, если через VK, то выводит input с ссылкой на его профиль, если steam, то стим профиль.
Но проблема в том, что не могу правильно написать проверку!

```
[t._v("Пользователь")])])]), t._v(" "), n("div", {
            staticClass: "col-lg-5"
        }, [n("label", [t._v("Профиль VK:")]), t._v(" "), n("div", {
            staticClass: "kt-input-icon"
        }, [n("input", {
            staticClass: "form-control",
            attrs: {
                type: "text",
                disabled: ""
            },
            domProps: {
                value: "https://vk.com/" + t.user.steamid64 + ""
            }
        }, [t._v("Пользователь")])])]), t._v(" "), n("div", {
            staticClass: "col-lg-5"
        }, [n("label", [t._v("Профиль STEAM:")]), t._v(" "), n("div", {
            staticClass: "kt-input-icon"
        }, [n("input", {
            staticClass: "form-control",
            attrs: {
                type: "text",
                disabled: ""
            },
            domProps: {
                value: "https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" + t.user.steamid64 + "/"
            }
        }),
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]